# Cannot use the F12 key as a shortcut key in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, batch

I've got a batch file that I am trying to launch from the keyboard.  I created a shortcut for this batch file and can successfully use F1-F11 as the Shortcut Key.  I can *set* F12 as the shortcut key, but it does not run the batch file when I hit it.  I downloaded a program called Shortcut Key Explorer to see if another program was already using F12, and there is not.  Any ideas why I cannot use F12 as a shortcut key?

Answer (score 0):

F12 has never worked as a shortcut key for me. I assume it's just not supported for some odd reason. You could try [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) and see if that works.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed?  I wonder if it is because F12 is reserved for "Jump to definition".  I hadn't thought of that until I started working.